# How to determine CPU mode on HPUX ia64 and Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, smp

How do I determine whether the CPU mode is SMP, AMP or BMP on a HP-ux ia64 system?

I've had a google and everything is telling me to check /proc/cpuinfo but this file (or folder for that matter) does not exist on my system

Also could you tell me how to check this on Solaris?:
$ uname -a
SunOS my-sol-server 5.11 11.1 sun4v sparc

CPU is at 180% for some processes so I suspect SMP is being used as opposed to BMP but I need to confirm this before I go back to the unix guys

Thanks
G.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about HP-UX, but Solaris doesn't have a global CPU mode you can check like that.   The OS is SMP/NUMA, but allows you to bind processes to certain CPUs if desired, via the [pbind command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29031/pbind-1m.html)